# Enriching custom plugins with contributions

Tags: backstage

I am creating a backstage backend plugin that using the EntityProvider is mapping certain data to the backstage entity model, using certain mapping rules.

I want to let other developers contribute to this backend plugin in an efficent way, by adding their custom mapping rules. Eg. they would want to create a backstage relation "providesApi" between their components and APIs by providing their data, specific to their case (which i am not aware of in the current mapping that i am doing in the plugin). I want to allow custom mapping rules for them.

My question is how to let other developers contribute with their own mapping rules to my plugin in a user friendly way, is there a way for doing it nicely, sorry for the general question, i just want some ideas.